# Facing issue with parsing the following JSON String in Python

Tags: python, json

```
{"tradedDate":"29NOV2019","data":[{"pricebandupper":"77.05","symbol":"YESBANK","applicableMargin":"43.35","bcEndDate":"12-JUN-19","totalSellQuantity":"-","adhocMargin":"9.71","companyName":"Yes Bank Limited","marketType":"N","exDate":"03-JUN-19","bcStartDate":"06-JUN-19","css_status_desc":"Listed","dayHigh":"74.00","basePrice":"70.05","securityVar":"23.26","pricebandlower":"63.05","sellQuantity5":"-","sellQuantity4":"-","sellQuantity3":"-","cm_adj_high_dt":"03-APR-19","sellQuantity2":"-","dayLow":"67.55","sellQuantity1":"-","quantityTraded":"42,83,32,393","pChange":"-2.21","totalTradedValue":"3,03,130.83","deliveryToTradedQuantity":"18.95","totalBuyQuantity":"13,12,136","averagePrice":"70.77","indexVar":"-","cm_ffm":"14,283.27","purpose":"ANNUAL GENERAL MEETING\/ DIVIDEND - RS 2 PER SHARE","buyPrice2":"-","secDate":"29-Nov-2019 00:00:00","buyPrice1":"68.30","high52":"286.00","previousClose":"70.05","ndEndDate":"-","low52":"29.00","buyPrice4":"-","buyPrice3":"-","recordDate":"-","deliveryQuantity":"8,11,80,641","buyPrice5":"-","priceBand":"No Band","extremeLossMargin":"10.38","cm_adj_low_dt":"01-OCT-19","varMargin":"23.26","sellPrice1":"-","sellPrice2":"-","totalTradedVolume":"42,83,32,393","sellPrice3":"-","sellPrice4":"-","sellPrice5":"-","change":"-1.55","surv_indicator":"-","ndStartDate":"-","buyQuantity4":"-","isExDateFlag":false,"buyQuantity3":"-","buyQuantity2":"-","buyQuantity1":"13,12,136","series":"EQ","faceValue":"2.00","buyQuantity5":"-","closePrice":"68.30","open":"72.00","isinCode":"INE528G01027","lastPrice":"68.50"}],"optLink":"\/marketinfo\/sym_map\/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=YESBANK&amp;instrument=-&amp;date=-&amp;segmentLink=17&amp;symbolCount=2","otherSeries":["EQ"],"futLink":"\/live_market\/dynaContent\/live_watch\/get_quote\/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=YESBANK&amp;instrument=FUTSTK&amp;expiry=26DEC2019&amp;type=-&amp;strike=-","lastUpdateTime":"29-NOV-2019 15:59:59"}
```

This is the JSON string I am fetching from a website, 
I am trying to parse it using the Json.load as well as Json.load but  get the following error.

```
stock_data = get_hl(soup)
File "/home/shreel/oi-bot/oi.py", line 349, in get_hl
final_op = json.loads(json_str)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 1555 (char 1554)
```

My code is as follow :

```
    final_op = json.loads(json_str)
    print(final_op)
```

The variable json_str has that string I posted above.

Can anyone help me out understanding the error as well as how to go about to solve it?

P.S Not from Python Programming Background.

Comment: The only problem I found regarding python is that `false` generates an error because it should be `False`. Other than that, what do you wish to do with the json? Maybe I can help you there.

Comment: You need to extract and provide a [mcve] from your code. Also, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky First thing, is this really a JSON? I check it in Json Beautifier website and it worked. Hence I am guessing it to be JSON. I am looking to extract Day High and Day Low from this!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Ooops man! Absolutely missed. Give me a min or 2, I'll put it on

Comment: I cut-n-pasted your string and it loaded with `json.loads`.  Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Had to replace "false" with "False" to be able to use the given input in the example below

Based on the comments and the question, to get `DayHigh` and `DayLow` you must address this json object as a dictionary that contains nested lists and dictionaries. You must find where `DayHigh` and `DayLow` are located and then you can simply address them as you would in a dictionary with dictionaries and lists inside it. Here is an example:

```
json_data = {"tradedDate":"29NOV2019","data":[{"pricebandupper":"77.05","symbol":"YESBANK","applicableMargin":"43.35","bcEndDate":"12-JUN-19","totalSellQuantity":"-","adhocMargin":"9.71","companyName":"Yes Bank Limited","marketType":"N","exDate":"03-JUN-19","bcStartDate":"06-JUN-19","css_status_desc":"Listed","dayHigh":"74.00","basePrice":"70.05","securityVar":"23.26","pricebandlower":"63.05","sellQuantity5":"-","sellQuantity4":"-","sellQuantity3":"-","cm_adj_high_dt":"03-APR-19","sellQuantity2":"-","dayLow":"67.55","sellQuantity1":"-","quantityTraded":"42,83,32,393","pChange":"-2.21","totalTradedValue":"3,03,130.83","deliveryToTradedQuantity":"18.95","totalBuyQuantity":"13,12,136","averagePrice":"70.77","indexVar":"-","cm_ffm":"14,283.27","purpose":"ANNUAL GENERAL MEETING/ DIVIDEND - RS 2 PER SHARE","buyPrice2":"-","secDate":"29-Nov-2019 00:00:00","buyPrice1":"68.30","high52":"286.00","previousClose":"70.05","ndEndDate":"-","low52":"29.00","buyPrice4":"-","buyPrice3":"-","recordDate":"-","deliveryQuantity":"8,11,80,641","buyPrice5":"-","priceBand":"No Band","extremeLossMargin":"10.38","cm_adj_low_dt":"01-OCT-19","varMargin":"23.26","sellPrice1":"-","sellPrice2":"-","totalTradedVolume":"42,83,32,393","sellPrice3":"-","sellPrice4":"-","sellPrice5":"-","change":"-1.55","surv_indicator":"-","ndStartDate":"-","buyQuantity4":"-","isExDateFlag":False,"buyQuantity3":"-","buyQuantity2":"-","buyQuantity1":"13,12,136","series":"EQ","faceValue":"2.00","buyQuantity5":"-","closePrice":"68.30","open":"72.00","isinCode":"INE528G01027","lastPrice":"68.50"}],"optLink":"/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=YESBANK&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2","otherSeries":["EQ"],"futLink":"/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=YESBANK&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=26DEC2019&type=-&strike=-","lastUpdateTime":"29-NOV-2019 15:59:59"}

for keys in range(len(json_data['data'])):
    print(json_data['data'][keys]['dayLow'])
    print(json_data['data'][keys]['dayHigh'])
```

Output:

```
67.55
74.00
```

Also if there are multiple json objects/files you can place them in a loop and iterate through it. If you want to turn it into a table then you can create a dictionary and make a dataframe out of it:

```
data_to_df = {'dayLow':[],'dayHigh':[]}
for keys in range(len(json_data['data'])):
    data_to_df['dayLow'].append(json_data['data'][keys]['dayLow'])
    data_to_df['dayHigh'].append(json_data['data'][keys]['dayHigh'])
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data_to_df)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  dayLow dayHigh
0  67.55   74.00
```

Answer (score 0):

According to JSON standards, boolean values need to be lowercased (false / true). Read more [here](https://www.json.org/)

The API that you are using, doesn't abide by this, and hence it's causing the above error. If changing the API return value is not an option, a quick hotfix would be:

```
import re
json_str = re.sub(json_str, False, false)
final_ob = json.loads(json_str)
```